# Is there a code coverage tool for Python 2.4?

Tags: python, unit-tests, code-coverage

My project is limited to python 2.4 due to, unfortunately, an essential third party library. I have a number of tests written using the unittest module. I would like to track test coverage. Is there a code coverage tool for python 2.4? I believe [coverage.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage) does not work with python 2.4.

Comment: Python 2.4.6 was released in 2008.  You are in *deep.*

Comment: Oh I know. It's bad.

Comment: At least you don't have a professor teaching that C doesn't have a Boolean data type. It's been in the standard since C99! There will always be legacy code, and legacy knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coverage.py 3.7.1 runs on Python 2.4: https://pypi.org/project/coverage/3.7.1/